# NetworkError: 500 Internal Server Error on SignalR hub

Tags: asp.net-mvc, signalr, signalr-hub

When I am running the web site on my local computer it works properly, but when I uploading to my domain, its starts to generates this error. Same problem I have on two my applications on difference servers. Same is only implementation solution, what is ASP.Net MVC 3, C#. Both of my applications are running on "Full trust" prottection on IIS server. Locally it works fine but problems are on remote servers.

Applications are running fine, but returns there errors :( Here is screenshot from mozilla firebug/network.

[image]

Comment: If you have customerrors turned off, you should be able to open that request in your Network console and see the full response from the server which would include a stack trace and error type for further debugging.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I did it!!! I hope it helps others...

Only what is needed is add this line into *system.web* part of web.config:

```
<httpRuntime targetFramework="4.5" />
```

Answer (score 0):

I was getting the same error (500 Internal Server error) with my SignalR 1.x enabled web application and tried several suggestions here with no joy.  I really got nowhere until I was able to resolve the 500 error** to a 500.19 error (Config Error: Cannot add duplicate collection entry of type 'add' with combined key attributes 'users, roles, verbs' respectively set to '*, , ' ).

For me it ended up being a location section in duplicate that works OK against IIS7 (the same app deployed against IIS7 was working) but seems to be incorrect on a new server sporting IIS8:

In my web.config I had this defined:

```
 <location path="signalr/hubs"> 
    <system.web> 
        <authorization> 
            <allow users="*"/> 
        </authorization> 
    </system.web> 
    <system.webServer> 
        <security> 
            <authorization> 
                <add accessType="Allow" users="*"/> 
            </authorization> 
        </security> 
    </system.webServer> 
 </location>
```

I changed it to

```
 <location path="signalr/hubs"> 
    <system.web> 
        <authorization> 
            <allow users="*"/> 
        </authorization> 
    </system.web> 
    <system.webServer> 
        <security> 
            <authorization> 
                <!--add accessType="Allow" users="*"/--> 
            </authorization> 
        </security> 
    </system.webServer> 
 </location>
```

And hubs started returning a 200 OK.

**99% of the problem was resolving the 500 error to something specific.  What helped me was using Firefox Console, recreating the error in the network tab, highlighting that 500 error on hubs and then using the Response and Preview tabs to get fine detailed information.  That information led me to the web.config setting above which pointed straight to the offending line in web.config!  Perhaps someone else can find happiness in my pain.